# How to convert SQL group by query to Linq query in join statment:

Tags: sql, linq

I am new to LINQ and don't know how to write group by query. I have two table Person and Salary, I have sql query:

```sql
Select Person.Unit, count(Person.Unit) as QuantityPeron, sum(Salary.Val) as SumSalary 
from Person, Salary 
where Person.Person_id = Salary.Person_id 
group by Person.Unit
```

I am try:

```cs
var sumarySalary = (
    from c in _context.Person 
    join l in _context.Salary on c.Person_id equals l.Person_id
    group c by c.Unit into to g 
    select new 
    { 
        Units = c.Unit, 
        QuanPer = c.Unit.Count(), 
        TotVal = g.Val.Sum() 
    }).ToList();
```

but errors

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: `into to` is typo? Also provide our model classes and EF Core version.

Comment: Show the errors! They're there to help you debug the problems...

Answer (score 0):

First, I should note that your SQL is not good and using old style joins.
Second, with a well designed database if you simply use model generators, you get a model that you don't need to use Join at all. In Linq, Join is needed very seldom for specific cases, other than that you simply use "dot navigation" to access related data:

```
var sumarySalary = (
    from c in _context.Person 
    select new 
    { 
        Units = c.Unit, 
        //QuanPer = c.Unit.Count(), this one is questinable
        TotVal = c.Salaries.Sum(s => s.Val) 
    }).ToList();
```

Your SQL is questinable that it has count(Person.Unit) in it. Based on your data bothg your SQL and this Linq might be totally wrong.